# Python Permission error when running EC2 EFS mount helper

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, debian, amazon-efs

Im trying to run the mount helper on a Debian 9 EC2 instance

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs.html#mounting-fs-mount-helper-ec2

running the following (with my own correct file path and EFS ID)

> $ sudo mount -t efs fs-12345678:/ /mnt/efs

I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sbin/mount.efs", line 674, in <module>
    main()
  File "/sbin/mount.efs", line 668, in main
    mount_tls(config, init_system, dns_name, path, fs_id, mountpoint, options)
  File "/sbin/mount.efs", line 630, in mount_tls
    with bootstrap_tls(config, init_system, dns_name, fs_id, mountpoint, options) as tunnel_proc:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/sbin/mount.efs", line 391, in bootstrap_tls
    start_watchdog(init_system)
  File "/sbin/mount.efs", line 367, in start_watchdog
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['/sbin/status', WATCHDOG_SERVICE], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

From looking around Google it seems I need to run Python with admin rights somehow? I have tried setting

> /sbin/status

to chmod 777

Answer (score 0):

Solution - The mount EFS code does not support sysvinit.. switch over to systemd

https://major.io/2014/05/20/switching-to-systemd-on-debian-jessie/